# HTTP Content-Type video/mp4 warning in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

I have a video that is embeddedin in a webpage.

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    AddType video/ogg .ogv
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4
    AddType video/webm .webm
</IfModule>
```

HTML:

```
<video autoplay="false" width="586px" height="440" src="...mp4"></video>
```

I use the mediaelement.js player:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer();
```

In firefox the video does not preload and it does not show the preview image. The player is just black. In firebug I get this warning:

> HTTP "Content-Type" "video/mp4" is not supported. Failed to download
>   media ...

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What video type are you trying to play? I don't see a `src`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox supports Ogg Theora and WebM video. It does not support MP4 (H.264) video.

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works

Comment: However when I click on play button it works. The video is played in firefox. This is weired

Comment: The video is probably played by a plugin. When I open an mp4 file directly in Firefox, the video is also played, but with the Quicktime plugin